# Remove ${ and } from a string with some specific pattern

Tags: java, regex

Input String:

```
<#if (${val1}-${val2}) + ${f1(${a}+${b}*${c})} > 2000>ABC<#elseif ${n1}+${n2}* ${f1(${n3}-${n4})} < 500>DEF</#if>
```

We want to remove All  `${` and `}` that are present in `<#if` and `<#elseif`, apart from the ones that are present inside `f1()` (`${` associated with `f1` should get removed as well). So, the expected output string is:

```
<#if (val1-val2) + f1(${a}+${b}*${c}) > 2000>ABC<#elseif n1+n2*f1(${n3}-${n4}) < 500>DEF</#if>
```

Comment: i have tried this textToReplace=textToReplace.replaceAll("(?<=(?!<#else>)<#|\\|\\||&&)(.+?)\\$\\{(.+?)\\}", "$1$2");

but it seems to remove just 1 ${}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex:

```
(?<=if \(|elseif )\$\{([^}]*)\}([+-])\$\{([^}]*)\}
```

Replacement:

```
\1\2\3
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/nJ8cJ8/36)

Your code would be,

```
String s1 = "<#if (${val1}-${val2}) + ${f1(${a}+${b}*${c})} > 2000>ABC<#elseif ${n1}+${n2}* ${f1(${n3}-${n4})} < 500>DEF</#if>";
String m1 = s1.replaceAll("(?<=if \\(|elseif )\\$\\{([^}]*)\\}([+-])\\$\\{([^}]*)\\}", "$1$2$3");
String m2 = m1.replaceAll("\\$\\{(f1[^)]*\\))\\}", "$1");
System.out.println(m2);
```

Output:

```
<#if (val1-val2) + f1(${a}+${b}*${c}) > 2000>ABC<#elseif n1+n2* f1(${n3}-${n4}) < 500>DEF</#if>
```

First `replaceAll` method removes  `${}` which was present just after to the `if` and `elseif`. And the second `replaceAll` method removes  `${}` symbols which was  wrapping around `f1`.

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/Lyjp9P)

Comment: I tried it with your expression and i m getting this output <#if (val1-val2) + ${f1(${a}+${b}*${c})} > 2000>ABC<#elseif n1+n2* ${f1(${n3}-${n4})} < 500>DEF</#if> which is partially fine. I want to remove ${} wrapping the function f1 too

Answer (score 1):

This problem is a classic case of the technique explained in this question to ["regex-match a pattern, excluding..."](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23589174/)

We can solve it with a beautifully-simple regex:

```
f1\([^)]*\)|(\$\{|\})
```

The left side of the alternation  `|` matches complete `f1( things )`. We will ignore these matches. The right side matches and captures `${` and `}` to Group 1, and we know they are the right ones because they were not matched by the expression on the left.

This program shows how to use the regex:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("f1\\([^)]*\\)|(\\$\\{|\\})");
Matcher m = regex.matcher(subject);
StringBuffer b= new StringBuffer();
while (m.find()) {
    if(m.group(1) != null) m.appendReplacement(b, "");
    else m.appendReplacement(b, m.group(0) );
}
m.appendTail(b);
String replaced = b.toString();
System.out.println(replaced);
```

**Reference**

- [How to match (or replace) a pattern except in situations s1, s2, s3...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23589174/)
- [Article about matching a pattern unless...](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html)

Comment: Can u please tell how to use it

Comment: Added sample code and explanation. Let me know if you have questions. :)